# How make: nth-last-child(1 + odd)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to make something like `nth-last-child(1 + odd)`, where the last child is affected but **ONLY if the element is odd**.

`nth-last-child(1 + odd)` doesnt work though, so what should I do?

---

**Bonus:** A more flexible answer allowing me to grab the last child, only if it is odd and the odd child before it.

```
<ul>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>affected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>affected</li>
</ul>
```

but if the last child is EVEN, nothing happens, so:

```
<ul>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
  <li>not effected</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to make something like `nth-last-child(1 + odd)`, where the last child is affected but **ONLY if the element is odd**.

As has already been addressed, `:nth-child(odd):last-child` (or vice versa — order of pseudo-classes doesn't matter).

> **Bonus:** A more flexible answer allowing me to grab the last child, only if it is odd and the odd child before it.

I'm not sure I would consider this more flexible, but selector syntax is pretty limited right now so it's the best you've got:

```
:nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(3),
:nth-child(odd):last-child
```

`:nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(-n+3)` comes pretty close, but that will match the *second last child* if that child is odd-numbered, which is not what you want.

Nothing a little negation couldn't handle if you really must have a single compound selector though:

```
:nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(-n+3):not(:nth-last-child(2))
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest a slightly different approach using two pseudo-classes:

```
:nth-child(odd):last-child
```

This first selects all odd child elements, and refines the selection to only the last-child of the parent element.

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  counter-increment: spanIndex;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25%;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
}

span::before {
  content: counter(spanIndex, decimal-leading-zero);
}

span:nth-child(odd):last-child {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
```

Comment: This is great however it limits me to only the last odd child. This is what I asked so this is why you get the correct answer, but what if I wanted the last TWO children, both must be ODD, to be affected?

Comment: The two last children can't both be odd; but based on the fact you want the odd last-child and its preceding sibling to both be selected then simply use a similar approach, with the additional selector: `:nth-child(even):nth-last-child(2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can combine both selectors like this:

```
:last-child:nth-child(odd)
```

**DEMO**
http://codepen.io/dschu/pen/XmbKmq

**SCSS**

```
ul 
{
  li
  {
    &:last-child:nth-child(odd)
    {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know who gave me a downvote. Anyway, you should mark one answer is correct

Comment: You have my upvote :) and you both have the correct answer but I'm looking for something a little more flexible if I wanted to say, make the last child that is odd AND the odd child before it have a red background. I've added this to the question. Whoever answers first, gets the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

CSS is a weird programming language. In other languages, we have AND or `&&`; in CSS we accomplish this by **stringing selectors together**: (no spaces or commas):

```
div#foo.bar[attr="baz"]:first-child
```

selects any element

- the type of which is DIV **and**
- the id of which is `foo` **and**
- one of the classes of which is `bar` **and**
- whose `attr` attribute has the value `baz` **and**
- is in the first child position.

In your case you want the element which is the last child **and** in the odd position, so you string them together as above. You used the expression **but only if**, but that of course is exactly the same as **and**.

#### Or

That's how **and** works; what about the other basic logical operation, which is **or**? In CSS, that's expressed by specifying **multiple selectors selected by commas**, so

```
div, #foo, .bar, [attr="baz"], :first-child
```

selects any element

- the type of which is DIV **or**
- the id of which is `foo` **or**
- one of the classes of which is `bar` **or**
- whose `attr` attribute has the value `baz` **or**
- is in the first child position.

#### Not

The last basic logical operation, of course, is **not**. How would I express this in CSS? Now we have the `:not` pseudo-class, but it has some limitations and can sometimes trip you up. The classic CSS approach to **not** is to give two rules, one more general and one giving the exceptions. Taking the example of "not the first child":

```
div { color: blue }
div:first-child { color: inherit; }
```

which means, "make the `div` blue if **not** the first child.

Comment: What question is this attempting to answer, exactly? "How to express a plain-English condition in CSS"?

Comment: @BoltClock Well, the question was *I want to make something like nth-last-child(1 + odd), where (1) the last child is affected [**and**] (2) the element is odd.* So yes, it's trying to explain some basics of how to represent that **and**.